# How could I create a dynamic URL redirect?

Tags: url, redirect

I want mywebsite.com/STUFF to redirect anotherwebsite.com/STUFF
So basically, I want a certain part of the URL I type ("STUFF") to be inputted into the redirected URL. Is this possible?
P.S.: Using Apache

Comment: What HTTP server are you using? Apache, Nginx... ?

Comment: Anyone want to help me?